# Visualizing Instagram Travel photo locations on a Map

Tags: travel, instagram

I uploaded many of my pictures on Instagram and tagged their location. Unfortunately [Instagram got rid of their photo map](https://www.theverge.com/2016/9/6/12817340/instagram-photo-map-removals). I loved this feature. There are many third party developer trying offering this feature. All I tried so far are either super expensive or do not work properly. 
Is there a (in the best case free or at least cheap) good website or an app that offers this feature?

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Travel stackexchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155081/visualizing-instagram-travel-photo-locations-on-a-map)

Comment: Please don’t cross-post question across multiple Stacks.